# VAR with dummies, how to analyze dummy effect?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, vector-autoregression

I'm currently trying to perform a VAR model analysis. I have the following variables, all on a one-minute scale, with 900 entries.

Put in eViews as endogenous:
Y1: Amount of tweets per minute
Y2: TV ratings
Put in eViews as exogenous, because they are dummies:
X1: Times when social media encouragement was on-screen (0,1)
X2: Emotional moment (0,1)

I would like to test the effect of X1 on Y1 and in my VAR I get a coefficient of around 150. Which can be correct, according to this graph.

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P0JP.png)

Now, most papers do not use these coefficients but test the effect of a shock. Though, this is only possible for the endogenous variables Y1 and Y2. I cannot find any research where the effect of a dummy in a VAR is explained.

Can anyone help me get into the right direction? Do I use the VAR coefficient or can I do other tests with these dummies?

Thanks so much, I'm pretty much stuck here!